# Sticky header + sticky social bar (mobile) = too much that is sticky?

Tags: scrollbars, header, social

Is it too much have *both* a sticky header (at the top of the viewport) and a sticky social bar (on the bottom) on mobile devices???

A sticky header is important for the user, but a sticky social bar is the most important for me (popularity, views, SEO)...

Maybe I should have a button to hide (or show) the social bar?  What do you think?

Comment: We need more context in order to provide a real answer. Either that, or you will need to make your question more general.

Comment: More context ? I ask that is too have header and social bar sticky. Is too ?? Maybe i should to put a button to hide the social bar ? Where is the problem ? Your answer is the same like my other ask

Comment: @user3162975 the point is that it depends on the application.  What content do you need to show?  Who are your users?  How is the app used?  etc.  Sometimes this would be a bad idea, other times it may be appropriate.

Comment: Is a responsive website, i will show text (article) and image. Is a scientific website (nature, volcanoes, quake ecc).

Comment: @dan1111 read my comment ?

Comment: for me having moving social icons is a very bad thing (tm). Accidentally clicking on share to facebook....its a worry. Even if I'm looking at nothing bad and there is always a confirmation first.

Comment: Also if is a small fixed bar ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Jquery to hide the nav bar when scrolling down and show the footer, and vice versa when scrolling up.  Something like Chrome on Android and iOS would do. Use CSS3 animations instead of Jquery .animate( ).

Comment: This site is for considering user experience, not implementation.  This doesn't answer whether it makes sense from a UX standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Is the social bar used frequently by your users?

If it's not remove it without any hesitation. If it is useful only for you as a developer and not for the users, the answer is clear - get rid of it.

Screen space on mobile devices as you know is very limited, so you need to maximise the viewport. In my opinion the sticky header is OK if it's slim, and the footer social bar is lowering the viewport which is frustrating the users because they have to scroll more to view the content.

Comment: Lukanow i don't know if the social bar will be used frequently.... it is useful first for me (popularity, seo and views) but i think is useful (because is a shortcut) for user that want to share a page/article. What do you think if i put a button in the social bar where if click it, the bar hide (therefore remains only the button) ?

Comment: Ok, what type of app is this, give me more information about your app so I can give you better answer? If it is not a social media oriented app, the footer bar will only harm your user experience, as users will be frustrated by the small viewport.

Comment: Is a responsive website about nature (earthquakes, volcano, tsunami, theory ecc). So i think that there will be many interesting articles that the user could to share. I would like to put a sticky social bar (only for mobile) because i believe that is better for views and SEO to have a visible shortcut to share my articles. But i hope that you answer me also about the possibility to put a button to hide or show the social bar. Thanks a lot

Comment: Lukamov read my comment?

Comment: You can instead use a share button, rather than a sticky social bar at the footer. This way you will save screen space and have the share functionality. This is my suggestion.

Comment: I have thought of this solution, but do you think that the "normal" people (for example my parents XD) know that the social icon is to share an article ?

Comment: I would advise you to use just one "Facebook" or "Twitter" icon depending on what your audience is familiar with( or maybe local social media). If you present multiple options for sharing, the chance someone to share your content decreases significantly, so please put only one icon to increase the number of shares.

Comment: So you suggest that is better to use only one "share button" for example "facebook" ??? And why if i have multiple options for sharing, they decreases ??

Comment: Hey man, don't get excited that much, you need to learn. Read more about **choice paradox** or **choice paralysis**, and you will answer your question. You can watch video [here](https://www.ted.com/talks/barry_schwartz_on_the_paradox_of_choice?language=en)

Comment: I read your link and thank you! It was very interesting! But however i think that few options are important.. I would like to put in social bar only "facebook, twitter, google plus"... Maybe is better didn't add also "whatsapp" button (to copy link and send with app). What do you think? Are too options?